# Save data of select list after clicking save

Tags: php, plugin-development, metabox, save-post, dropdown

I already have a meta box in the edit post that has a select list with custom taxonomies. But after i save the post the select list returns it value to none, **so i don't know how to save the selected value**. Can't solve this as i can't figure other codes that don't deal with this one.

Here's my php that creates the metabox and the select list:

```
<?
function prfx_custom_meta() {
add_meta_box( 'prfx_meta', __( 'Reproductor 1', 'prfx-textdomain' ),     'prfx_meta_callback', 'post' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'prfx_custom_meta' );

function prfx_meta_callback( $post ) {
wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'prfx_nonce' );
$prfx_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
?>

<p>
<label for="Netu" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Netu', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></label>
<select name="Netu" id="Netu">
<option value="Ninguno" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['Ninguno'] ) ) selected(        $prfx_stored_meta['Ninguno'][0], 'Ninguno' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Netu', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></option>';
<option value="Netu" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['Netu-cast'] ) ) selected(        $prfx_stored_meta['Netu-cast'][0], 'Netu Castellano' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Netu 
Castellano', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></option>';
<option value="Netu-vose" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['Netu-vose'] ) ) selected(  $prfx_stored_meta['Netu-vose'][0], 'Netu Inglés Subtitulado' ); ?>><?php _e( 
'Netu Inglés Subtitulado', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></option>';
<option value="Netu-latino" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['Netu-latino'] ) )    selected( $prfx_stored_meta['Netu-latino'][0], 'Netu Latino' ); ?>><?php _e( 'Netu Latino', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></option>';
</select>
</p>
```

And here's the one that should save the value:

```
 <?php }
 function prfx_meta_save( $post_id ) {

// Checks save status 
$is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
$is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
$is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[          'prfx_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

// Exits script depending on save status
if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
return;
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'prfx_meta_save' );

if( isset( $_POST[ 'Netu' ] ) ) {
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'Netu', $_POST[ 'Netu' ] );
}

if( isset( $_POST[ 'Ninguno' ] ) ) {
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'Ninguno', $_POST[ 'Ninguno' ] );
}

if( isset( $_POST[ 'Netu-cast' ] ) ) {
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'Netu-cast', $_POST[ 'Netu-cast' ] );
}

if( isset( $_POST[ 'Netu-vose' ] ) ) {
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'Netu-vose', $_POST[ 'Netu-vose' ] );
}

if( isset( $_POST[ 'Netu-latino' ] ) ) {
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'Netu-latino', $_POST[ 'Netu-latino' ] );
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `add_action` that's supposed to hook your `prfx_meta_save` function inside the function itself, so it never gets hooked or called. You need to move the `add_action` outside the function.

This will never work:

```
function prfx_meta_save( $post_id ) {
    add_action( 'save_post', 'prfx_meta_save' );
}
```

Move it outside the function:

```
function prfx_meta_save( $post_id ) {
    // your save code
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'prfx_meta_save' );
```

Comment: Done... Still not working...

Comment: how is it not working? is the meta value saved?

Comment: The meta value does not save and returns to none

Comment: are you sure it's not saving? your issue is in the code that sets the previous selected option, not the code that saves the value.

Comment: This code has driven me crazy... made a different question with another code: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154575/second-select-list-values-are-not-saved-after-clicking-update